Thunderbird displaying incorrect From value in GitHub notifications
I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS yesterday, which entailed an upgrade to Thunderbird 128.3.1esr (64-bit).  (I have been using both Ubuntu and Thunderbird for many years. This is the first time I have used a snap-based Thunderbird rather than an apt-based one.)  Following the upgrade, in one particular folder every message now displays the same, incorrect value for "Correspondents" and that same value for the "From" in each individual message within that folder.
The folder in question holds messages generated by posts to the "Issues" and "Pull Requests" queues in a GitHub.com repository, specifically, (List-Id) Perl/perl5 <perl5.Perl.github.com>.  (You can see the original post on GH here.) In the Thunderbird tree listing of messages I see the "Correspondents" for this message displayed as "H.Merijn Brand" -- as is the case for all other messages in this folder. In the message pane I see the "From" displayed as "H.Merijn Brand" as well.  However, if I hover the mouse pointer over the "From" value, the pop-up indicates the real value of "From":  "James E Keenan <notifications@github.com".
If I double click to display the message in a new tab, the "From" value is also displayed as "H.Merijn Brand", even though hovering over the "From" value indicates that the message really came from "James E Keenan <notifications@github.com".
When I go to my email service provider's web interface, I see the "From" value displayed correctly for all messages, i.e., the messages are not all visibly attributed to "H.Merijn Brand".  So this problem is specific to the way this version of Thunderbird is rendering the messages.  Can anyone provide guidance?

The same problem occurred to me under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS today after Thunderbird was upgraded from 115.16.2 to 128.4.2. I worked around it by disabling the Show only display name for people in my address book checkbox in the settings.
